# TypeScript + React: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, postcss

I realize that there are several questions related to this error floating around, but as far as I can tell this is a unique situation and not related to an incorrect `import` statement.

I'm building a `React` component library with `TypeScript` and `webpack`.

My directory structure:

```
- src
  - index.ts
  - components
    - Button
      - Button.tsx
      - index.ts
      - Button.css
      - Button.d.css (generated by webpack plugin)
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- webpack.config.js
- postcss.config.js
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "dist",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts",
    "**/*/*.test.ts",
    "examples"
  ]
}
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index.js"
  },
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              namedExport: true,
              banner: "/* This file is generated during the webpack build. Please do not edit/remove. */",
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              config: {
                path: './postcss.config.js'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ],
  devtool: "source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".css"]
  }
};
```

My `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    modules: true,
    plugins: [
        require('precss'),
        require('postcss-simple-vars'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
        require('postcss-nested'),
    ]
}
```

`src/index.ts` is simply:

```
import { Button } from './components/Button';

export {
  Button,
};
```

`src/components/Button/index.ts`:

```
import Button from './Button';

export { Button };
```

and `src/components/Button/Button.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as styles from './Button.css';

export interface IButtonPropTypes {
  onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<any>;
  label: string;
  children?: ReactNode[] | string;
  kind?: 'link' | 'action';
  style?: { [key: string]: string };
  href?: string;
  target?: string;
  className?: string;
}

export default function Button({
  onClick,
  label,
  children,
  kind = 'action',
  style = {},
  href,
  target,
  className,
}: IButtonPropTypes) {
  const text = label || children;
  const kindStyle = styles[kind] || '';
  const classes = className || '';
  if (href) {
    return (
      <Link
        className={`${style.btn} ${kindStyle} ${classes}`}
        to={href}
        target={target}
        onClick={onClick}
        style={style}
      >
        <span className={style.background} />
        <span>{text}</span>
      </Link>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button className={`${style.btn} ${kindStyle}`} onClick={onClick} style={style}>
      <div>{text}</div>
    </button>
  );
}
```

My `dist` folder after running `webpack` looks like:

```
- dist
  - index.js
  - index.js.map
  - index.d.ts
  - main.css
  - main.css.map
  - components
    - Button
      - Button.d.ts
      - index.d.ts
```

and [`dist/index.js`](https://gist.github.com/adrice727/685ea1abb8ba1dcbe47ef5014f88e4d0) seems to be compiled correctly by `webpack`.  In `package.json`, I have:

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": ["dist"]
```

After running `yarn link`, I import and use my `Button` component in a standalone app like so:

```
import { Button } from 'my-components';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button label="click me" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and receive the following error:

> ```
> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> ```
>
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
>   it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> ```
> Check the render method of `App`.
> ```

If I remove the `Button` component, `App` renders without any errors.

*Testing by publishing a throwaway module to `npm` yields the same error.*

Additionally, if anyone has any suggestions as to better ways to bundle this library, I'd love to hear them as this is my first time using `postcss`.

Comment: Did you omit your `export` statement in your `App.tsx` file...?

Comment: @Andrew No, I just didn't include it in the code snippet.  I'll make an edit so it's not confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, this was due to an issue with my `webpack` config.  Adding the following lines to `output` fixed the error:

```
  output: {
    . . . 
    library: "opentok-ux-components",
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you made a small mistake importing in `index.ts`. Since it's a default export, no curly braces should be used.

```
import Button from './components/Button';
```

Comment: Apologies, but upon closer inspection, I'm very confused as to what is going where. This might be incorrect then.

Comment: The duplicate `index.ts` files are a little confusing.  `src/components/Button/index.ts` exports the `default` from `Button.tsx`.  `src/index.ts` picks up that import and exports it.